# linux history command

Tags: linux, shell

If I type history command, I can view only 1000 lines. I want to view more than that. It will be nice If I can view all commands typed between certain dates or months.

Is this possible? If so, how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this posting on Stackoverflow can help:

[link](http://serverfault.com/questions/170872/which-command-to-know-the-time-when-a-server-has-booted-up-boot-time-history)

Comment: Technically the history command is a SHELL command and not a linux command. So how it behaves depends on what shell you are running.

Comment: sounds like you want to use this to log usage?  If so, there are better ways to monitor the commands.

Comment: @nycynik : Can you please elaborate on other ways you are talking about?

Comment: sure one is http://sourceforge.net/projects/rootsh/ and lastcomm is a command to review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set the bash variables `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` in your `.bashrc`.

`HISTSIZE` determines how many comands are retained in history. `HISTFILESIZE` determines how many lines of history are stored in the file in which they are persisted, usually `.bash_history`.

Answer (score 0):

add some commands to .bash_logout to organize your history files

e.g.

```
today=`date +%y%m%d`
cp .bash_history >.bash_history_$today
echo >.bash_history  # to clear out file
```

However, one problem: .bash_logout doesn't seem to run in a lot of X-based environments.  On a ssh account, such as with a virtual server, it works fine.